# Help hide path outline for the pen tool in B-Spline mode in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I need to be able hide the red path outline for the pen tool in BSpline mode as it starts to overlap the blue line and causes annoyance when you're trying to draw small, accurate paths and don't want to zoom in on them.

If hiding wouldn't be possible, being able to change the color of both the outline (red) and the curve line (blue) would suffice.

[image]

Comment: There's no way I can think of.  There doesn't seem to be an option in the preferences to change that behaviour.  The colour of the red outline can be changed - but it would take effect only after you have created the shape, but not as it is being drawn.  I suppose if you feel so inclined, you could reprogram the behaviour, since Inkscape is open source, but that's way beyond the scope of GDSE.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, Inkscape's user interface doesn't give a way to fade the red lines which appear between the clicks when you draw a BSpline.

One workaround is to draw the paths as Bezier curves. In math both methods can produce the same set of curves, so you do not lose possible forms nor cause a need of more clicks, but you gain two things:

- Bezier curve is more basic form of path in Inkscape, there to be a BSpline means the same as to be a polyline-like Bezier curve with BSpline path effect.
- You define explicitly some points that the Bezier curve goes through, with BSplines you can set explicitly only the start and end.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is this.

1. show page border- Under -> files-> Document Properties
2. Put your design inside the page border
3. select only the bezier curve and move it outside the page border
4. Go to export tab, and choose "Selection" ( other options will be page, drawing...)
5. Now export to a given file path. 
   Hope it helps